# unmarshal incoming JSON request using JAXB2Marshaller

Tags: json, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have the following spring config:

```
<bean id="exportMarshallerJson" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <list>
            <value>com.foo.bar.export.jaxb</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:exportxsd/schema.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.media-type">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="eclipselink.json.include-root">
                <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="jaxb.encoding">
                <value>UTF-8</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output">
              <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="unmarshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.media-type">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="eclipselink.json.include-root">
                <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, I am able to marshal Java objects into JSON string with the above marshaller, but incoming JSON strings do not get unmarshalled correctly with above unmarshaller.

The exception is:

> **[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.**

I can't use Jackson or other JSON unmarshallers since my requirement is to validate against XSD.

I have tried to debug and seems like the underlying "platformUnmarshaller" never gets the eclipselink.mediatype property "application/json".

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: `eclipselink.json.include-root` set to `false`?

Comment: I have same problem! Any solution?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately not. I have tried a couple of things since then, but this has been put on our backburner for now.